# Remove Button for Tkinter Frame created through a function

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a set of codes that will create a subframe through a function. This was made a function because I connected it to a button that if clicked will add new set of identical subframes.

My concern now is that I would also need a remove button beside the add button. However, I do not know the name of these frames made by this function. I tried to look for similar cases but the one I found is made from class, not by function.

Is there a way around for this, or I really have to convert my function into a class? Thank you.

Here is my current set of codes (with add button but no remove button yet):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Database(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        parent.state('zoomed')
        self.parent = parent     
        
        MainFrame=Frame(self)
        MainFrame.pack(expand = True, side = TOP, fill="both")
        
        
        frames = []

        def New():
            global widgetNames
            global frameNames
            
            DataFrameAF_=LabelFrame(frame,bg = "blue", text="Sub Info")
            DataFrameAF_.pack(side = TOP, padx = 10, pady = 10, fill = BOTH, expand = True)

            DataFrameAc = Frame(DataFrameAF_)
            DataFrameAc.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 5)

            self.lbl_1=Label(DataFrameAc, text = "A1                                    ")
            self.lbl_1.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=W)

            self.txt_1=ttk.Entry(DataFrameAc, width=20)
            self.txt_1.grid(row=1,column=1)

            self.lbl_2=Label(DataFrameAc, text = "A2                                    ")
            self.lbl_2.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W)

            self.txt_2=ttk.Entry(DataFrameAc, width=20)
            self.txt_2.grid(row=2,column=1)

            self.lbl_3=Label(DataFrameAc, text = "B1                                    ")
            self.lbl_3.grid(row=1,column=2,sticky=W)

            self.txt_3=ttk.Entry(DataFrameAc, width=20)
            self.txt_3.grid(row=1,column=3)

            self.lbl_4=Label(DataFrameAc, text = "B2                                    ")
            self.lbl_4.grid(row=2,column=2,sticky=W)

            self.txt_4=ttk.Entry(DataFrameAc, width=20)
            self.txt_4.grid(row=2,column=3)
            
            #remove the New Button and include the Add button inside the new subframe
            NewButton.pack_forget()
            AddButton = Button(DataFrameAF_, text="ADD", command=New)
            AddButton.pack(side=BOTTOM)



        DataFrameAF=LabelFrame(MainFrame, text="Information")
        DataFrameAF.pack(side = TOP, pady = 10, expand = True, fill = BOTH)
        
        canvas = Canvas(DataFrameAF, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
        frame = Frame(canvas, background="#ffffff")
        vsb = Scrollbar(DataFrameAF, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
        canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)

        vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        canvas.pack(side="left", fill=BOTH, expand=True)
        canvas.create_window((20,20), window=frame, anchor="nw")
        
        def reset_scrollregion(event):
            canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

        frame.bind("<Configure>", reset_scrollregion)
        
        
        #Button for adding New Subframe
        NewButton = Button(frame, text="New", command=New)
        NewButton.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill="x")
        

root = Tk()
database_window = Database(root)
database_window.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The structure of the code is probably the mistake here.

Comment: Are you aware you're overwriting all of the variables for each row? For example `self.txt_1` will always only ever point to the last row that was created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```py
from functools import partial

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Database(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        #parent.state("zoomed")
        self.parent = parent     

        MainFrame = Frame(self)
        MainFrame.pack(expand=True, side="top", fill="both")

        self.frames = []

        DataFrameAF = LabelFrame(MainFrame, text="Information")
        DataFrameAF.pack(side="top", pady=10, expand=True, fill="both")
        
        self.canvas = Canvas(DataFrameAF, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
        self.frame = Frame(self.canvas, background="#ffffff")
        vsb = Scrollbar(DataFrameAF, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)

        vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.canvas.create_window((20,20), window=self.frame, anchor="nw")

        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.reset_scrollregion)

        #Button for adding New Subframe
        self.NewButton = Button(self.frame, text="New", command=self.new)
        self.NewButton.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")

    def reset_scrollregion(self, event):
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

    def new(self):
        global widgetNames
        global frameNames
        
        DataFrameAF_ = LabelFrame(self.frame, bg="blue", text="Sub Info")
        DataFrameAF_.pack(side="top", padx=10, pady=10, fill="both", expand=True)

        self.frames.append(DataFrameAF_)

        DataFrameAc = Frame(DataFrameAF_)
        DataFrameAc.pack(side="left", padx=5)

        self.lbl_1 = Label(DataFrameAc, text="A1                                    ")
        self.lbl_1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")

        self.txt_1 = ttk.Entry(DataFrameAc, width=20)
        self.txt_1.grid(row=1,column=1)

        self.lbl_2 = Label(DataFrameAc, text="A2                                    ")
        self.lbl_2.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="w")

        self.txt_2 = ttk.Entry(DataFrameAc, width=20)
        self.txt_2.grid(row=2, column=1)

        self.lbl_3 = Label(DataFrameAc, text="B1                                    ")
        self.lbl_3.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="w")

        self.txt_3 = ttk.Entry(DataFrameAc, width=20)
        self.txt_3.grid(row=1, column=3)

        self.lbl_4 = Label(DataFrameAc, text="B2                                    ")
        self.lbl_4.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky="w")

        self.txt_4 = ttk.Entry(DataFrameAc, width=20)
        self.txt_4.grid(row=2, column=3)
        
        #remove the New Button and include the Add button inside the new subframe
        self.NewButton.pack_forget()
        AddButton = Button(DataFrameAF_, text="ADD", command=self.new)
        AddButton.pack(side="bottom")

        remove_button = Button(DataFrameAF_, text="Remove", command=partial(self.remove, DataFrameAF_))
        remove_button.pack(side="top")

    def remove(self, frame):
        frame.destroy()
        self.frames.remove(frame)
        if len(self.frames) == 0:
            self.NewButton.pack()


root = Tk()
database_window = Database(root)
database_window.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```

I tried to make the code more pythonic but that is all that I can do in the limited mount of time. As for the "Remove" button, I used `partial` to pass the frame in the `remove` method which destroyed it. If the destroyed frame was the last, it packs the "New" button. If you want to know how `partial` works look at the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution for your code is to pass the frame to the button's command.

For example:

```
RemoveButton = Button(DataFrameAF_, text="DEL", command=lambda frame=DataFrameAF_: frame.destroy())
RemoveButton.pack(side="top")
```

Comment: Yes but what if the user removes the last frame? Nothing will be left on the screen.

Comment: @TheLizzard: yes, that is one of several problems with the code. This just answers the question that was asked, which is how to know the name of the button that was clicked.